# How can I share a WorkerThread between most activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, service

I wanted to know if there is a way to create a common WorkerThread to all activity. This thread needs to open a socket, send a command, read the response and send it to the various activity. I tried to use an IntentService with a BroadcastReceiver but I have noticed that the commands sent from the activity are run one by one, respecting a queue. In my case, I need instead of a thread which is able to execute a command one by one but at the same time also to terminate an already running command to start a new one. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's shared between Activities like that should be owned by a Service instead.  Both Activities can start and/or bind the service to make sure they can connect to it.

You do not need to use an IntentService.  IntentService is for queueing items to be run serially on its own Thread.  Use the base Service class instead.

Comment: Worth noting that a Service will block the Main thread, unless you use a Service with a ThreadPool or AsyncTask with an Executor etc..

Comment: No it won't.  Not if he uses a Thread, which is what we're talking about.  No need for a thread pool.  An AsyncTask will be added to the same AsyncTask thread as all other tasks, unless used with an executor.

Comment: Just noting, that IF the code from the intentService is adapted directly (which uses its own worker thread for you), then without adapting it by creating your own worker thread then it would block the Main thread. To quote myself "unless you use a Service with a ThreadPool or AsyncTask with an Executor etc."

Comment: How can I stop a running command to run a new one without stopping the service?

Comment: If you need that type of control, then you'll need to code it yourself.  Canceling in process requests can be tricky, and really depends on your entire system architecture.  The simplest way is to cancel the existing Thread and starting a new one, but if you need to maintain the same socket connection you get really complicated (is the other side capable of canceling?  What happens to data en route?  etc).